# Divs with children not stacking properly

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t2w4yd8j/1/

I have a couple of questions about this:

1) There seems to be a padding between the `.top` div(red) and the browser if I use the relative position. However if I change the position of `.top` div(red) to absolute the padding goes off. Why is that?

2) The `.next` div(pink) should stack after the `.main` div(grey). But the main div seems to be taking a bit more extra space even though the height is set to auto and there is no children in the extra space. Why is that?

Thanks

**CSS**

```css
.main{
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#CCC;
}
.top{
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#F00;
}
.middle{
    position:relative;
    top:-25px;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:3;
}
.midfill{
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:#0F0;
}
.bottom{
    position:relative;
    top:-50px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#00F;
}

.next{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#F0F;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="main">
        <div class="top"></div>
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="midfill"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="next"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, can you be a bit more clear: what is it that you are trying to do (ie what will it look like when it's working properly)?

Comment: By default css properties will get applied to all the html elements. You can test the css properties using inspect element. So if you see, body will get margin:8px; by default. So if you remove this by using margin:0 to body. You can make it work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) By placing it relative, it relates to it's parent, the body tag. Remove the padding and margin from the body and HTML tag, and it fits. When you place the div absolute, it's taking out of the document flow, making it relate to the viewport. That explains the difference.

```
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

2) you position the div's relative, and then move them around. But the place stays reserved in the parent div. I moved the divs a bit around.

```
html, body { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
}
.main{
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#CCC;
}
.top{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#F00;
}
.middle{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -25px;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:3;
}
.midfill{
    display: inline-block;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#0F0;
}
.bottom{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#00F;
}

.next{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#F0F;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/t2w4yd8j/3/)

Comment: I don't know if you need both `.middle` and `.midfill` for some reason, but you could also accomplish this layout without `.middle`: https://jsfiddle.net/t2w4yd8j/4/

Comment: This worked. Thanks :)  I need .middile because In my actual code I don't know midfill's width.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for your both problem  is following. By Default it takes extra margin by removing it from body solved your issue:

```
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/t2w4yd8j/2/)

Comment: The padding problem is gone. But there is still that grey area which shouldn't be there. The height of .main is more than it's children's height